# How to transpose columns to rows with additional commas added to it using python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
1FCD

1FCE

1FCF

1FD0

1FD1
```

I want above data to change it like below. I could able to add the commas but couldn't able to transpose it to rows.

Target  - `1FCD,1FCE,1FCF,1FD0,1FD1`

`import sys
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line.rstrip()
        dev = line[:-1]
        DEV = (dev + ",")
        print (DEV)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `csv.reader` and `str.join`:

```
from io import StringIO
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""1FCD

1FCE

1FCF

1FD0

1FD1""")

with mystr as fin:
    reader = map(itemgetter(0), filter(None, csv.reader(fin)))
    res = ','.join(reader)

print(res)

1FCD,1FCE,1FCF,1FD0,1FD1
```

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? The solution *does* work if you copy-paste the above code precisely. Either it's not implemented correctly, or the data is different to my example.

Comment: The input is not defined data it will be varying everytime so I tried to give mystr = input("""devices:""") instead of StringIO. Iam getting  AttributeError: __exit__  error.

Comment: Could you help me how to add input with StringIO option??